# How can I iterate over tweepy Cursor? For loop is not working

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I was trying to fetch some tweets with tweepy and I keep getting the error `'Cursor' object is not iterable`.

My code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)  
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)  
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
                 wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="some-query",  
                               tweet_mode="extended",
                               lang="it",
                              result_type = "recent",
                               count = 100)
```

This code is not working, it works calling `api.search` outside the `Cursor` object but it does not paginate the results apparently and it retrieves always the same 100 tweets.

What am I missing here? All the example I see are within a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked adding `tweets.next()` at the end of the loop.

```
url = "https://twitter.com/"  
status = "/status/"
response = []
    
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.created_at, url + tweet.user.screen_name +
                         status + tweet.id_str, tweet.full_text) 
    response.append([tweet.created_at, url + tweet.user.screen_name +
                         status + tweet.id_str, tweet.user.screen_name,
                         tweet.favorite_count, tweet.retweet_count,
                         tweet.full_text])
    tweets.next()
```